# cache/memoize method call across different instances objects python

Tags: python, function, caching, memoization

I am trying to figure out a good way to cache the results of a method call across different instances of an object. I can modify the memoize decorator to remove the first argument (which is always self) of the method call, or I can remove the core of the method from the class and create a new function and then have the method call the new function (and memoize that function). I'm looking for guidance on this. Maybe there is something I have missed or another solution.

In this example expensive_calc() is a static method, but in my application it is not. Assume that it will always return the same data regardless of the object properties as long as the function parameters are the same. Also given how my application is designed, it is much more convenient to keep it as a class function.

```
from time import sleep

class Test(object):

    def expensive_calc(self, arg, kwarg1):

        sleep(5)

obj1 = Test()
obj2 = Test()

obj1.expensive_calc(1, kwarg1=1)
obj2.expensive_calc(1, kwarg1=1) # Would like this use the cache
```

Comment: I dont understand what cache has to do with any of this, could you explain?

Comment: What is not clear? I am trying to figure out how to cache the results of a method call instead of re-running the expensive_calc() each time. The code here is simplified example of the structure of the problem.

Comment: The use of the word cache is confusing her since it is usually used in terms of processor cache memory. I now understand what you want to do, do you have a constant amount of arguments?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion maybe I should have written memoize to be more clear. The function does not have a constant number arguments, but that should not be an issue. This is a solved problem for regular functions if you use the memoize decorator, but I'm trying to get it working for a bound method of a class.

Comment: Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign variables to the class definition with `self.__class__`

Here is an example

```
class Test:
    def self_assign(self):
        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'storage'):
            self.__class__.storage = 'useful data'
    def get_self_assign_value(self):
        return getattr(self.__class__, 'storage')
```

In use:

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:class Test:
  :  def self_assign(self):
   :     if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'storage'):
 :           self.__class__.storage = 'useful data'
  :  def get_self_assign_value(self):
       : return getattr(self.__class__, 'storage')
:<EOF>

In [2]:

In [2]: test1 = Test()

In [3]: test2 = Test()

In [4]: test1.get_self_assign_value()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-88e253d48023> in <module>
----> 1 test1.get_self_assign_value()

<ipython-input-1-e186ef60b5aa> in get_self_assign_value(self)
      4             self.__class__.storage = 'useful data'
      5     def get_self_assign_value(self):
----> 6         return getattr(self.__class__, 'storage')

AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'storage'

In [5]: test2.get_self_assign_value()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-60a245b44dc0> in <module>
----> 1 test2.get_self_assign_value()

<ipython-input-1-e186ef60b5aa> in get_self_assign_value(self)
      4             self.__class__.storage = 'useful data'
      5     def get_self_assign_value(self):
----> 6         return getattr(self.__class__, 'storage')

AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'storage'

In [6]: test1.self_assign()

In [7]: test1.get_self_assign_value()
Out[7]: 'useful data'

In [8]: test2.get_self_assign_value()
Out[8]: 'useful data'
```